# Criptografia de parâmetros de requisição GET e POST

Tags: java, aplicação-web, segurança, criptografia

Sou iniciante em java e estou estudando java web, principalmente Servlets e JSP. E preciso desenvolver uma aplicação web como trabalho de faculdade, focado na segurança. Pra isso gostaria de encriptografar os parâmetros das URL's (no GET) e também os parâmetros passados no header via POST. Gostaria de fazer isso manualmente, sem uso de HTTPS.

Mas a dúvida é como funcionaria essa arquitetura (chamar classe que encriptografa/descriptografa toda vez que entrar em uma página). Alguém já fez algo parecido? Teria uma dica?

Comment: Se você quer fazer isso com fins de aprendizado, há várias bibliotecas JavaScript que realizam a criptografia, e com o HTML5 há inclusive uma solução nativa - o WebCrypto - que oferece vários algoritmos. Na prática, no entanto, a arquitetura seria complexa e há muitos detalhes chatos, demais pra explicar numa resposta, pra fazer certo demandaria um livro. O HTTPS (HTTP sobre TLS/SSL) funciona porque todos esses detalhes já foram bem pensados e a criptografia funciona a nível de transporte, ou seja, tudo o que é transmitido, inclusive os parâmetros do GET e do POST, já vai encriptado.

Answer (score 3):

Você utilizaria algum algoritmo de chave assimétrica, e com ele encriptaria a *query string* do GET ou o corpo da requisição POST usando a chave pública antes de enviá-lo ao servidor (use javascript para fazer isso). No servidor você recupera a informação original descriptografando ela com a chave privada.

Entretanto, eu não recomendo você seguir essa linha para o seu trabalho de faculdade. Isso que você está tentando é apenas uma forma de reinventar uma roda quadrada. Ou seja, uma solução caseira e medíocre para um problema para o qual já existe uma solução muito superior, padronizada e amplamente conhecida.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Mas existe algum meio simples e já existente de encryptografar a URL no GET ? Esse padrão já existente, você se refere ao HTTPS ?

Comment: @Mehrune Você pode procurar por aí a função de encriptar que você preferir. Procure por criptografia de chave assimétrica em javascript. Entretanto, você só vai poder encriptar a query string da URL, e não a URL completa, senão o navegador não entenderia essa URL e não poderia utilizá-la. O HTTPS já supera todos esses problemas.